# como adiciona um resultado do prompt em uma Array?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Quero adiciona um resultado do meu Prompt em uma array .Essa array passa por um For loop que divide ela em duas (name e preço), adiciona o nome dela e do preço em uma lista il, e soma o preço de todos os produtos em baixo.

Deu certo tudo isso, porém não consigo fazer um push para adiciona novos produtos na array clicando no button, como resolver?

```js
const lista = document.querySelector(".block ul ");
const priceTotal = document.querySelector(".block p");
let total = 0;

lista.innerHTML = "";
priceTotal.textContent = "";

const btn = document.querySelector(".btn")

let products = [
"Chápeu:9.50",
"Camiseta:15.40",
"Calça:50.20",
"Óculos:20.80",
"Sapatos:100.10"
]

for(const product of products){
const item = product.split(":")
const name = item[0]
const price = Number(item[1])
total += price
const itemText =`${name} - $$${price}` 

const listitem = document.createElement("li")
listitem.textContent = itemText
lista.appendChild(listitem)
}
priceTotal.textContent = `Total: ${total.toFixed(2)}`

btn.addEventListener("click",( ) =>{
   const ask =  prompt ("deseja adiciona um produto? [sim ou não]")
    if(ask == "sim"){
        const newproduts = prompt("digite o nome e o preço igual ao exemplo a seguir [name:preço]")
        products.unshift(newproduts)
        console.log(products);
   }
   else if(ask !== "sim"){
    alert("tenha um bom dia!!")
   }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="js2.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
  

    <div class="block">
    <h3>Block of Price</h3> 

    <ul><li>0</li></ul> 

    <p>Total:</p>
    <button class="btn"> New Product?</button>

    </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: pessoal , o resto esta ok , só essa parte do event click que parece que esta errado, quero saber só essa parte.

Comment: ja tentou usar o metodo .add para adicionar?

Comment: O seu código está funcionando, o array está sendo preenchido. O que deve estar faltando é você verificar o carregamento do dom [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) ou colocar o javascript no final da tag body. Obs.: o array preenchido no javascript não quer dizer que irá automaticamente atualizar o html na página.

Comment: realmente foi adicionado a arrays, mas agora como faça para atualizala?

Answer (score -2):

Tente usar

```
products.push(newporducts);
```

Comment: Tentei mas não deu